# R Shiny App - how to sort elements of this reactive list

Tags: r, sorting, reactive-programming, shiny

I am trying to sort elements of a csv file that has been added via a shinyapp.

I'm having trouble understanding how to sort the items by the first column within my code. Here is a snippet of the code with my attempt to sort my list. The original full code/question is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562445/r-shinyapp-how-to-open-and-plot-from-csv-getting-error-attempt-to-select-les)

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        filedata <- reactive({
                infile <- input$datafile
                if (is.null(infile)) {
                        # User has not uploaded a file yet
                        return(NULL)
                }
                read.csv(infile$datapath)
        })

# my attempt to sort
                filedata() <- filedata()[ order(filedata()[[input$selectcol1]]) ]



        x <- reactive({
                1:dim(filedata())[1]
        })

        output$selectcol1 <- renderUI({
                df <-filedata()
                if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

                items=names(df)
                names(items)=items
                selectInput("selectcol1", "Best Estimate",items)

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this step

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        filedata <- reactive({
                infile <- input$datafile
                if (is.null(infile)) {
                        # User has not uploaded a file yet
                        return(NULL)
                }
                temp<-read.csv(infile$datapath)
                #return
                temp[order(temp[, 1]),]

        })
```

and removing

```
# my attempt to sort
                filedata() <- filedata()[ order(filedata()[[input$selectcol1]]) ]
```